# creating some page with wp_insert_post but don't want to add some page in menu

Tags: wordpress

I am creating a plugin and creating some required pages with "wp_insert_post" function in wordpress and "Auto add pages" is on in menu section so when I am creating pages all pages adding in menu. but I want to add only some page in menu. also don't want to off "Auto add pages" for menu. Can I do this with plugin script?

Comment: I think this is question is too general! What kind of menu (primary)? Is the menu generated with `wp_list_pages()`? Is this a plugin to be used on wordpress.org?

Comment: I want to add new created pages in menu but not all and that is problem.

Comment: sorry, but your reply doesn't address my questions or narrows down the question with more details, so I can't help you further on this one, but best of luck with the question, cheers.